# Printing First two numbers in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to print the first 2 numbers in a list coded in Scheme. I'm having a bit of trouble doing this. I get an error when I run the procedure.  Any suggestions on how I can get this to work

(define (print-two-nums n nums)

( list-ref nums(+ (cdr nums) n)))
( print-two-nums  2'(5 5 4 4))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were wavering between the ideas of "print two numbers" and "print *n* numbers." If you really want just the two first numbers of a list, you can write:

```
(define (print-two-nums nums)
  (print (list (car nums) (cadr nums))))
```

But for the more general first *n* numbers, you can use:

```
(define (print-n-nums n nums)
  (print (take nums n)))
```

Comment: I needed to print n numbers so the second example you gave me would be the one. However, Im having problems implementing it

Comment: How come? Are you using a subset of Scheme that doesn't have "take"? If that is the case, you can roll your own using `cons`, `car`, and `cdr` instead.

Comment: It tells me that --- print: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier

Comment: Trying replacing "print" with "display".

Answer (score 0):

To print the first `n` numbers, you could use this simple procedure

```
 (define (print-n-nums L n) (cond
                   ((or (= 0 n) (null? L)) '())
                   (else (cons (car L) (print-n-nums (cdr L) (- n 1))))))



(print-n-nums (list 1 2 3) 2)
;Output: (1 2)
```

You could further **abstract** the `cons` operation and define `print-n-nums` as a higher order procedure to carry out the desired operation. For example, if we wanted to add the first `n` numbers of a list, we could define the following procedure. Here `OPERATION` is a function that we pass to the `list-operator` function. Thus, here we want to perform the `+` operation. In the case above, we want to perform the `cons` operation. The `initial` parameter is just how we want to handle the edge case.

```
(define (list-operator L n OPERATION initial) (cond
           ((or (= 0 n) (null? L)) initial)
           (else (OPERATION (car L) (list-operator (cdr L) (- n 1) OPERATION initial)))))

(list-operator (list 1 2 3) 2 + 0)
;Output: 3
```

Now, if you wanted the product of the first `2` numbers, you would just do

```
(list-operator (list 1 2 3) 2 * 1)
```